# Распарсить таблицу в MySql

Tags: php, mysql

имеется простая таблица

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#C0C0C0" cellpadding="0" 
width="100%"><tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p align="center"><strong>№ Карты</strong></p></td>
<td bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p align="center"><strong>Пользователь</strong></p> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p align="center"><strong>Баланс</strong></p></td>
</p></td>
</tr><tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">001641</td>
<td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
<td><p align="right">100,00</p></td>
</tr><tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">001679</td>
<td>Антонов Артём Анатольевич</td>
<td><p align="right">200,00</p></td>
</tr><tr>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

нужно достать № Карты, Пользователь, Баланс
и
запихнуть в Mysql таблицу.
№ Карты не повторяется.
Требуется помощь средствами PHP.

Comment: попробуйте http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php. Еще  очень много библиотек для парсинга html  кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохраните в переменную `$str` код таблицы, и на выходе получите необходимые параметры:

```
$str = ''; // HTML код таблицы

$patt = '~(?<=<td bgcolor="#ffffff">).+?(?=</td>)'.
    '|(?<=<td>)[\pL\s]+(?=</td>)'.
    '|(?<=<p align="right">).+?(?=</p>)~us';

preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

$arr = array_map(function($a){
    return array_chunk(array_map('trim', $a), 3);
}, $arr);

$arr = $arr[0] ?: null;

echo '<pre>', print_r($arr, true), '</pre>';
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 001641
            [1] => Иванов Иван Иванович
            [2] => 100,00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 001679
            [1] => Антонов Артём Анатольевич
            [2] => 200,00
        )

)
```